# oracle - two unrelated categories on row - how to index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an OLTP application with three tables

```
Item Table - ItemId, CategoryId, AgeGroupId, ... 100K rows. 

CategoryTable - CategoryId, ...  (only 5-10 rows)
AgeGroupTable - AgeGroupId, ...  (only 4-5 rows)
```

What is appropriate index for `CategoryId` and `AgeGroupId` for Item table? It would be nice to query items by `Category` or `Agegroup` or both of them!

I was thinking that a bitmap index might work due to low cardinality, but I don't know how exactly they work with multiple bitmap indexes per table? How would horizontal partitioning help, if at all?

Comment: If you're talking about bitmap indexes, does that imply that this is a data warehouse environment?  Because bitmap indexes generally aren't appropriate in an OLTP environment (though more recent versions create fewer problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an OLTP application, you almost certainly don't want to use a bitmap index.  Bitmap indexes tend not to work well with OLTP applications.  They tend to grow in size very rapidly when you do a lot of single-row operations on the data (though this effect is lessened in more recent versions).  But more importantly, the locking impact tends to radically reduce the scalability of an application.  If you had a bitmap index on `CategoryID`, for example, updating a single row's `CategoryID` would effectively require locking every row in the table that has a `CategoryID` of either the source or target value.

It sounds like, at most, you need composite indexes on (`AgeGroupID`, `CategoryID`) and (`CategoryID`, `AgeGroupID`).  Potentially, you could use just the composite index on (`AgeGroupID`, `CategoryID`) and let Oracle use an index skip scan if only `CategoryID` is specified.  It depends on the trade-offs you want to make-- multiple indexes will make queries just on `CategoryID` more efficient at the expense of additional index maintenance on DML operations and additional disk space usage.

Are you licensed to use partitioning?  That is an extra cost option on top of the enterprise edition license.  Potentially, I suppose, you could partition the table.  A table with just 100,000 rows is pretty small to consider partitioning, though.  And whatever you partition by would tend to make queries that don't use the partition key less efficient.  That might make sense if you know that queries that specify `AgeGroupID` are much more common than `CategoryID` (or vice versa) but that doesn't sound like what you are describing.

Comment: Items are rarely updated, if at all. It's an OLTP application, but items are not updated - maybe inserted every few months.

Comment: @user1831003 - OK, so the table is completely static for 2 months at a time?  Do you have a window to rebuild the index after inserting data every two months?

Comment: how long would rebuilding the index take for 100k rows? :)

Comment: @user1831003 - Obviously, it depend on your system and how big the table is.  A few minutes likely.

Comment: +1 I would say that having two indexes ((Age, Cat) as well as (Cat, Age)) in this particular scenario is unnecessary - a query on just one of the columns will probably ignore the indexes anyway. The index is probably only useful when the query has predicates on both columns.

Answer (score 2):

This started off as a comment, but it's getting too long.

> What is appropriate index for CategoryId and AgeGroupId?

In what context? Both data domains appear as primary and foreign keys in your example schema. However this beside the point.

You should only add indices where they are actually going to add value, and with less than 10 rows in each table, unless the data is *very* skewed, there's no benefit to indexing either domain at all. Inserts/updates will be slower and accessing the data via such an index will be slower than performing a full table scan on each of the 3 tables.

There may implicit relationships between other attributes in the item table whereby it makes sense to add the domains to other indexes (but not at the front) but without knowing a lot more about the data and the queries being run against it, I'd ignore this for now.

Comment: +1 - Exactly.  If the data is evenly distributed each `AgeGroup` will define 20% of the Items and `Category` will define, at best, 10% of them.  These are not access paths where indexes will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what your queries look like.  If you are always going to be filtering on or joining on only one column at a time, then bitmap indexes will work fine.  If you will be filtering or joining based on both columns, a composite index can work as well.

In my experience, the best way to know for sure is to test both options.  I have had success putting multiple bitmap indexes on a table, as well as using composite indexes.  With only 100K rows in a table, you should be able to create and drop indexes very quickly.  Then you can test your most common queries on with different sets of indexes.

Comment: what about partioning? when does that come in handy?